# ImpressPages add pages custom fields

Tags: php, admin, custom-fields, impresspages

I need to add custom fields to a Page.

I created a Plugin that manages the Categories/SubCategories. But now I can't find how can I show the category field on the "Add Page Modal" view without editing the original file inside Ip/Internal/Pages.

As the override folder in themes is only for views is there a way to override/extend internal controllers?

E.g:
- adding multiple tags, categories, etc.
- A widget that filters the pages that have the selected tags (!= alias, because is not unique)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely add your fields to page details. Check the plugins for examples (this plugin adds it's own section - http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/PageImage).

However, I doubt that you can add fields to a modal. If you really need this, create a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I needed. I was missing the concept of ipPageStorage, Events and Forms, but now I understand. Thanks.